# How to use tesseract.js to extract handwritting text from image?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, handwriting

I hope to use tesseract.js but it seems not working properly with handwritten text.
Public trained data that I used works with only printed text, I think.

I tried to research trained data for handwritting by googling but not found yet.
Can anyone provide some tips or helpful links?